# Why my yfinance Ticker.info only returning regularMarketPrice and logo_url

Tags: python, yfinance

i need get info country and sector from stock apple

```
apple = yf.Ticker("AAPL")
apple.info
```

but output info im get just {'regularMarketPrice': None, 'logo_url': ''}
if im try

```
apple['country']
```

error message will because there no key country

my yfinance ver 0.1.67 and try upgrade 0.1.90 still same problem

Comment: Please do not post images of code/data/errors: [see this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Also, please consider posting a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: This is an open issue github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/issues/1246

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

Just update yfinance to the latest version. 1.93

pip install yfinance==0.1.93

Comment: oh thank you that work. im just check today latest version 0.2.1